# socket bad file descriptor

Tags: sockets, file-descriptor

I want to write a multi clients socket program, 
but I get Bad file descriptor when the stage of accept.
How can I correct my code? Thanks!

Here is my code
http://codepad.org/q0N1jTgz
Thanks!
Here is my part of code!

```
while(1)
{
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);

    /*Accept*/
    if(clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen) < 0)
    {
        perror("Accpet Error");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    /*Fork process*/
    if(child = fork() < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork Error");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(child == 0)
    {
        int my_client = clientfd;
        close(sockfd);

        send(my_client, welcome, sizeof(welcome), 0);

        while ((res = recv(my_client, buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), 0)) > 0)
        {
            string command(buffer1);
            cout << "receive from client:" << command << ", " << res << " bytes\n";
            memset(buffer1, '\0', sizeof(buffer1));     
        }
    }

    close(clientfd);

}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code in your question by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13287359/edit). The codepad will go away any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few bugs in your code
first you need to use parentheses around the assignments for `child` and `clientfd`.

line `68` should be changed to

```
 if((clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0)
```

and line `76` should be

```
  if((child = fork()) < 0)
```

additionally you must `return` or `exit()` from the forked process since you have already closed the listening socket.

so add `exit(0);` or `return 0;` after line `94`

I highly recommend you compile your code with warnings enabled, to catch the assignment problems early. e.g use the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags if you are using `gcc` or `g++`

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very useful for me, I will correct my code and retry it. THANKS!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: now, the program works perfect, but there is an another problem is that the clientfd is always a same number, server can't recognize what exactly which client send message, how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @ChengChung-Hao The only thing that distinguishes clients is their IP address:port, which you can get from the socket FD via getpeername().